# Solution verification: $G$ and $G/H$ contain elements of same order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

I just took my abstract algebra midterm, and was wondering if someone could confirm my solution to the following problem.

> **Problem:** Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer and suppose there exists an element
>   of order $n$ in $G/H$. Prove that there exists an element of order $n$
>   in $G$.

**My Solution:** Since $H$ is a normal subgroup, there exists a surjective homomorphism $\varphi: G \to G$ such that $\ker(\varphi) = H$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem,

$$
G/\ker(\varphi) \cong \varphi(G).
$$

Since $\ker(\varphi) = H$ and $\varphi(G) = (G)$ (since $\varphi$ is surjective), this becomes

$$
G/H \cong G
$$

which implies that

$$
|G/H| = |G|.
$$

Since $G/H$ and $G$ are of the same order, if $G/H$ contains an element of order $n$, $G$ must as well.

Comment: The correct formula is $$|G/H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$$ at least for finite groups, and there are non-isomorphic groups of the same order, so your argument is incorrect on two fronts.

Comment: No, your interpretation of the First Isomorphism Theorem is wrong. From $|G/H|=|G|$ it would follow that $|H|=1$. So you have proved that every normal subgroup is trivial ...

Answer (score 2):

If $(gH)^m=H$, so $gH$ has order $m$ in G/H, then $g^m\in H$ (why?). If $g^m=1$, then we are done, otherwise $g^m\in H$ has some order, $n$ say. So $g^{mn}=1$. Consider $g^n$...

This "breaks" for infinite groups, as $g$ might have infinite order in $G$. For example, consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ any non-trivial subgroup.

---

Also, I should say that your concluding sentences incorrect, so your attempt is unfortunately wrong. A counter-example to the last line is the groups of order 4: The Klein 4-group has order 4, as does the cyclic group of order 4, but the Klein 4-group does not contain en element of order 4 while the cyclic group does.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $a\in G/H$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\mapsto a$ under the canonical map $G\to G/H$. What can you say about the orders of $a$ and $g$? If $g^m=1$, what about $a^m$?